# ng-style and ng-disabled initially evaluate as true even though boolean is false in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, boolean, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm running into a strange problem with `ng-style` and `ng-disabled` in the context of an `ng-repeat`. I have the following template...

```
        <li ng-repeat="value in currentFacet.values track by $index">
          {{ showAll }}
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="options[$index]" ng-true-value="'{{ value.label }}'" ng-checked="value.isActive" ng-disabled="showAll"/>
          <span ng-style="showAll ? {color:'gray'} : {}">{{ value.label }}</span>
        </li>
```

Which produces a list of checkboxes. There is a `showAll` boolean which disables all of these checkboxes.

Initially when the page loads it seems that `ng-style` and `ng-disabled` evaluate as if the boolean had been true...even though when I viewed the current status of the boolean (That's why that `{{ showAll }}` is in there) it was false.

If I change the boolean to true and then back to false the functionality works as expected. It is only on the initial page-load that this udnesired behavior occurs.

Comment: can you share the controller code also?

Comment: @NarenMurali It should be irrelevant?

Comment: Just wanted some sample variables to replicate the issue,anyway fine

Comment: @NarenMurali The controller is pretty complicated. I think it would be more confusing than anything.

Comment: is your showAll variable is under some set timeout or initially changing under some ajax request ?

Comment: check type of showAll once, I am assuming initially it is string. that's why condition working fine on load. if('false') is true.

Comment: That was it. Duh. Answer and I'll accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check type of showAll once, I am assuming initially it is string. that's why condition working fine on load. if('false') is true.